# What is the difference between "It is necessary for him to do something" and "It is necessary that he do something"?

Tags: grammar, questions, subjunctive-mood

> It is necessary for him to do something.
>   It is necessary that he do something.

I know the second one is subjunctive and I know that it is used for command, demand, etc.

I want to know what difference does it make in the meaning?

Is subjunctive used in spoken language?

Examples:

> It is necessary for Tom to arrive at 5.
>   It is necessary that Tom arrive at 5.

Comment: The second sentence is not grammatical. It should be "necessary that he *does* something".

Comment: @AravindSuresh: Nah. As OP says, it's *subjunctive* - still perfectly "grammatical", even if it's increasingly falling out of favour (especially in colloquial/spoken contexts).

Comment: @J.R.: I didn't notice (now-corrected) ***necessarily***. I was addressing the implication of italicised ***does*** replacing original (and grammatical) ***do***.

Comment: @Aravind Suresh 'The second sentence is not grammatical. It should be "necessary that he does something".' is as incorrect as ' "It is necessary that he does something." is not grammatical.  It should be "necessary that he do something".' CGEL states that the three forms used (the other being the 'periphrastic _should_ construction) are all grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between *It is necessary for him to do something* and 
*It is necessary that he do something* is one of formality, not meaning.

The subjunctive *he do* in the second sentence is one of the six surviving  uses identified by Garner, in *Modern American Usage* (p780): namely, statements of necessity. He cites these examples:

> It's necessary that they *be* there.
>
> His entrance into the military made it necessary that he *use* the
>   birth-certificate version of his name.
>
> It will be necessary that he or she *have* a solid understanding of
>   school finances.

Garner states that the use of the subjunctive for statements of necessity is most common in writing, and is of the opinion that the usage is "*worth keeping*".

Peters in *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* (p520) lists *necessary* as one of the adjectives which "*introduce mandative clauses that typically take the subjunctive*". She states:

> The mandative subjunctive is regularly used in North American English
>   ... .
>
> In British English the mandative subjunctive declined during C20, perhaps because of Fowler's
>   (1926) general onslaught on the subjunctive, on the basis that it was
>   either misused or pretentious. ... British grammarians since then have
>   tended to say that it's primarily associated  with formal style.

Peters notes that "*British writers have expressed the mandative by means of the modal verb 'should'*".

I would add that it is also not unusual, in British English at least, to use the indicative. Here are some Google counter-examples to Garner's mandative subjunctives above:

> So it's necessary that they *are* self-sufficient.
>
> It's necessary that he *uses* that pen, otherwise ... .
>
> It's necessary that he *has* his infamously snazzy "Pirates of the
>   Caribbean" Jack Sparrow suit at the ready.