# Should we say "insisted that we attended" or "insisted that we attend"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, british-english

> She insisted that we **attend** the party.
> She insisted that we **attended** the party.

I know the following versions are correct (I'm only curious about the ones above):

> She insisted that we should attend the party.
> She insisted on us attending the party.
> She insisted on our attending the party.

Comment: This question is answered in [Does 'insisted' take indicative in the following sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/604578/191178), but the answer seems to be written about British usage, whereas American usage is only mentioned in a comment on that answer.

Comment: The first one is okay, but the second should be "She insisted that we **attend** with them."

Comment: It may help to look up "subjunctive".  For example, "She insisted that he attend the party"... not an error for "he attend**s**".

Comment: Do you want to write American English or British English?

Comment: British English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the question has been covered before, perhaps the regional and registral variations could be better addressed. Paraphrases are shown using equals signs:

- **[A1] She insisted that we attend the party**. [subjunctive mandative, = *[A3]* *She insisted that we should attend the party*, **or possibly** indicative with present simple for ongoing iterative situation: *She insisted that we regularly attend the party*. (the party a repeating event; use of distributive singular)]
- **[A2] She insisted that we attended the party.** [covert mandative with past simple, = *She insisted that we should attend the party*, **or** indicative, = *She insisted that we had attended the party.*]

The above, see [CGEL {Huddleston & Pullum, 2002, 7.1.1], which adds the caveat

> Clear cases of the covert construction are fairly rare, and indeed in
> 'AmE' [my scare quotes] are of somewhat marginal acceptability. In AmE
> the subjunctive is strongly favoured over the *should* construction,
> while 'BrE' shows the opposite preference.

So 'should we say' has no unique answer; the mandative sense would be seen as needing the subjunctive (A1) by the vast majority of Americans, while most Brits would prefer the simple past covert (A2) or the periphrastic should (A3) alternatives (with, I'd say, A2 the more usual, especially in conversation).

...................

For the sake of completeness, the other ways of expressing the mandation listed:

- **[B] She insisted that we should attend the party.** [uses declarative content clause =  that-clause] [common]
- **[C1] She insisted on us attending the party.** [uses ing-clause; ACC-ing construction]
- **[C2] She insisted on our attending the party.** [uses ing-clause; POSS-ing construction] [sounds rarefied in conversation, in the UK at least]

Answer (score 3):

In *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, Quirk et al. have a footnote on p.157 about the verb *insist*:

> The use of the subjunctive after *insist* depends on meaning. When
> the verb introduces an **indirect statement**, the indicative is used, but
> when it introduces an **indirect directive**, the subjunctive is more
> likely:
>
> She *insists* that he *is* guilty of fraud.
> We *insist* that he *be*
> admitted to hospital immediately.

Many speakers of AmE like to maintain this distinction between the indicative and the mandative subjunctive with *insist*:

"She *insisted* that he *attended* the party." (She was certain that she had seen him there.)

"She *insisted* that he *attend* the party." (She told him that he'd better come.)